# Error: Missing end time. Google Calendar API with Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I am realising example from Google Calendar API instruction web page. I put the code into example.js file and start it with *node example.js* in command line.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try **strong text**{
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

everthing is working allrigth.
But when I try to insert event to Google calendar with this code.

```
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), addEvent);

function addEvent(auth) {
    var event = {
      'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
      'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
      ],
      'attendees': [
        {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
        {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
      ],
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
      },
    };

var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    calendar.events.insert({
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event,
    }, function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
    });
```

I invariably get:

**There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Missing end time.**

What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I had a version of the google-auth-library that wasn't compatible with the most recent googleapis version. Check your versions - you might need to upgrade and migrate over your google-auth-library which is why the example above doesnt work for you.

Here's the edits you might have to do if this is your issue:
https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try mine:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvent);
});
/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}
/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}
/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function insertEvent(auth) {

var event = {
  'summary': 'This is a test Calendar invite using NodeJS',
  'location': 'Under the Bridge',
  'description': 'I dont ever wanna feel Like I did that day But take me to the place I love Take me all the way',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2018-02-25T12:58:05-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2018-02-26T06:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'rhcp@gmail.com'}

  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': true
  }
};

var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
calendar.events.insert({
  auth: auth,
  calendarId: 'primary',
  resource: event,
}, function(err, event) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
});
```

}

Proof the sample Quickstart is working. Events are inserted in my calendar:

[image]

Comment: I played with data, with time and dates. All the same. Your example isn't exclusion.

Comment: hmmm my nodejs sample is working, thats why i shared it.

Comment: That sounds promising. I am doing something wrong and have no idea what exactly. Can you share your js file?

Comment: sure, updated my answer. it's [Google's NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) mixed with [Google's insert event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) sample. Copy paste, it should work :)

Comment: like do you have a local webserver activated?

Comment: No, should I? I just do Step 4, run the sample using the following command:
node quickstart.js, first time I copy link - paste it to the browser - then copy response - and paste it back. Next time when I start with node quickstart.js I got mistake.

Comment: I re run my program and didn't need to use local web server, that's for Browser Quickstart not NodeJS. sorry. I think I pretty much did what I can to help. good luck

Comment: First the code didn't work either. The solution was to downgrade the package: googleapis@24.0.0 works --> with @25.0.0 i got the error ... and google-auth-library@0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having the same error as this one, using codes from examples and from @noogui. I found this library working as expected although requires a lot of configuration [node-google-calendar](https://github.com/yuhong90/node-google-calendar).

I also hope Google Calendar API will work soon.

Comment: It does work. I just showed you my screenshot of the event being added on my calendar using NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

googleapis@24.0.0 and google-auth-library@0.12.0 worked for me