# Google Calendar API - Missing End Time

Tags: google-calendar-api

Trying to use the Google Calendar API to get a list of events, getting returned with a 400 Error: Missing end time. Details below. Any suggestions?

**Body**

```
{"calendarId":"george.albrecht@xxx.com","timeMin":"2018-03-04T19:00:00+00:00","timeMax":"2018-03-07T19:00:00+00:00","timeZone":"America/New_York","showDeleted":true}
```

**Headers**

```
'Content-Type', 'application/json'
'Authorization', 'Bearer '+access_token
```

**Endpoint & Method**

```
Endpoint=https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/george.albrecht%40xxx.com/events, Method=GET
```

Answer (score 0):

`startTime` and `endTime` in body looks like these:

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'This is a test Calendar invite using NodeJS',
  'location': 'Under the Bridge',
  'description': 'I dont ever wanna feel Like I did that day But take me to the place I love Take me all the way',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2018-02-25T12:58:05-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2018-02-26T06:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'rhcp@gmail.com'}

  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': true
  }
};
```

If that solution  still doesn't work, try downgrading the package:

> googleapis@24.0.0 works --> with @25.0.0 i got the error ... and
>   google-auth-library@0.12.0 as mentioned in this [SO
>   post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393785/6143482).