# 'Missing end time' error when creating event using Google Calendar API for my Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

In my website, I have utilized the Google Calendar API to let users create an event. I have followed the instructions in the api guide but I am getting a missing end time error when I am trying to create an event. Here is my code:

```js
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const Config = require("./config");
const calendar_credentials = Config.calendar_credentials;
const calendar_token = Config.calendar_token;
const CAL_ID = 'somecalendar**********@group.calendar.google.com';

router.post('/create_event', (req, res) => { 
  authorize(calendar_credentials, createEvent);
    // Event information
  var event = {
    'summary': 'New Event',
    'description': 'This is a new event',
    'start': {
      'dateTime': '2020-07-17T16:00:00-04:00'
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': '2020-07-17T17:00:00-04:00'
    }
  };

  function createEvent(auth){
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
    calendar.events.insert({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: CAL_ID,
    resource: event,
    }, function(err, event) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
          return;
    }
      console.log('Event created successfully');
    })
  }
    
  res.send("Successfully created event");
})

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */


function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris);
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(calendar_token);
  callback(oAuth2Client);
}

module.exports = router;
```

I have the credentials and the token inside a .env file and I am extracting the values from it. Here is the code for that:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const calendar_credentials = {};
const calendar_token = {};

dotenv.config({path: './calendar/calendar.env'});

calendar_credentials.client_id = process.env.calendar_client_id;
calendar_credentials.project_id = process.env.calendar_project_id;
calendar_credentials.auth_uri = process.env.calendar_auth_uri;
calendar_credentials.token_uri = process.env.calendar_token_uri;
calendar_credentials.auth_provider_x509_cert_url = process.env.calendar_auth_provider_x509_cert_url;
calendar_credentials.client_secret = process.env.calendar_client_secret;
calendar_credentials.javascript_origins = process.env.calendar_javascript_origins;
calendar_credentials.redirect_uris = process.env.calendar_redirect_uris;

calendar_token.access_token = process.env.calendar_access_token;
calendar_token.refresh_token = process.env.calendar_refresh_token;
calendar_token.scope = process.env.calendar_scope;
calendar_token.token_type = process.env.calendar_token_type;
calendar_token.expiry_date = process.env.calendar_expiry_date;

module.exports = {calendar_credentials, calendar_token};
```

Also, this is the .env file:

```
calendar_client_id="someclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com"
calendar_project_id="some-project"
calendar_auth_uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
calendar_token_uri="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
calendar_auth_provider_x509_cert_url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
calendar_client_secret="someclientsecret"
calendar_javascript_origins="http://localhost:5000"
calendar_redirect_uris="http://www.example.com"

calendar_access_token="*******someaccesstoken*******"
calendar_refresh_token="*******somerefreshtoken*******"
calendar_scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
calendar_token_type="Bearer"
calendar_expiry_date=1594476438514
```

If I use the credentials from the credentials.json file, the event is created successfully but using the variables from the .env file results in the missing end time error. The token variables work properly from the .env file without any problem. I would really appreciate if someone could resolve my issue.

Comment: Have you checked that both `event` and `auth` are getting passed and populated correctly to the function `createEvent`?

Comment: Yes, I checked and they are being passed correctly.

Comment: I assume both the JSON file and the `.env` file refer to the same set of credentials, right? This might be a problem with the library versions, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48548102). Could you check that?